# returning a list from multiple mixed args

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a list of numbers either as a single number or a range, the expected input syntax will be: 1,2 ,3-5, 7,9 -4

The function will be returning a list of string 'numbers'.

So this will be: '1','2','3','4','5','7','9','8','7','6','5','4'. Spaces should be removed.

which will have duplicates removed: '1','2','3','4','5','7','9','8','6'.

It would be nice to have these ordered ascending, but optional

**Method**

My first issue seems to be accepting `3-5` as a string, it is automatically returned as `-2` so this needs to be identified and sent to `list(map(str, range(3, 5)))` [plus 1 to the highest number since it's python] this range can then be added to the list`l`.

Any single numbers can be appended to the list.

Duplicates are removed (solved).

The list is returned.

**My outline**

```
def get_list(*args):
    # input 1-10,567,32, 45-78 # comes in as numbers, but should be treated as string
    l=[] # new empty list
    n=str(args) # get the args as a string

    # if there is a '-' between 2 numbers get the range
    # perhaps convert the list to a np.array() then loop through?
    # I will need n.split(',') somewhere?
    l = list(map(str, range(3, 5)))
    
    # if just a single number append to list
    l.append()
    
    # remove duplicates from list
    def remove_list_duplicates(l):
        return list(dict.fromkeys(l))
    
    l = remove_list_duplicates(l)
    

    return l
```

Comment: *comes in as numbers* ?, if `1-10` then comes in `-9`?

Comment: If I do `def get_list(*args):
    return args` with `get_list(1,2-5,3)` it returns `(1, -3, 3)`

Comment: How could you know `-3` was get by `2-5` or `1-4` or `0-3` in the function?Python  will only pass `-3` to this function.

Comment: If I add `n = str(args)` and `return n` I get `'(1, -3, 3)'`

Comment: In this instance I want it to return `'1','2-5','3'`

Comment: So the first question is how to parse `2-5` as a string through `*args`

Comment: Impossible, why don't pass `get_list("1", "2-5", "3")`?

Comment: Hey dude, that get_list function is for the user i guess,then why not pass strings as arguments process these and return the answer..?

Comment: @AjaySinghRana thanks, ok I'll do it that way, any help with the main question?

Comment: I didn't get it what's your main question..?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for your problem:

```py
ranges = input()
ranges = ranges.split(',')    # i split the user input on ',' as i expect the user to specify the arguments with a ',' else you can split it on ' '(space)

def get_list(*ranges):
    return_list = []    # initialize an empty list
    for i in ranges:
        try:    # as these are strings and we need to process these exceptions may occur useexception handling
            return_list.append(int(i))    # add the number to the list directly if it can be converted to an integer
        except:
            num_1,num_2 = map(int,i.split('-'))    # otherwise get the two numbers for the range and extend the range to the list
            if(num_1 > num_2):
                return_list.extend([j for j in range(num_2,num_1 + 1 ,1)])
            else:
                return_list.extend([j for j in range(num_1,num_2 + 1 ,1)])
    return list(set(return_list))    # to return a sorted and without duplicates list use the set method

print(get_list(*ranges))    # you need to use the spread operator as the split method on input returns a list
```

##### Ouptput:

[image]